# Alignment issue for jquery validate generated message while using jquery mobile versions >1.2

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

After upgrading to jquery mobile 1.4.2, alignment of jquery validate error messages for

```
 <input id="field1" type="text" class="required" />
```

is wrong.

Please check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrfhU/155/)

Comment: Don't rely on jsFiddle alone, always put the complete concise example in your OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Mobile wraps `input` in a div that holds styles. The error message should be place outside that div. To do so, you need to modify `errorPlacement` in `$.validator.setDefaults`.

Based on returned `element`, you can place it `.before()` or `.after()` that div, or any other place you want.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if ($(element)[0].localName == "input") {
                $(element).parent().after(error);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $("#form1").valid();
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/33trw/)**